# Configure HTTPS by default for a single site on server

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I have a WAMP server with a few sites on it. I would like to enable SSL for default for only one of the sites.

While the https://www.example.com is accessible, there is no auto redirect happening for http://www.example.com.

Also `httpd -t` shows `Syntax Ok`

This is my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hi@santo.sh
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/example"
    ServerName http://manage.example.com/
    ServerAlias http://manage.example.com/   
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin hi@santo.sh
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/example/public"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp/OpenSSL/cert/sslcert.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp/OpenSSL/certs/mydomain.key" 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Added the exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**your error is here** : You are using instead %{HTTP_HOST} of %{SERVER_NAME}

This is 3 ways to redirect http trafic to https:

1 - Using redirect (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_alias.html)

which is recommended by apache : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com 
    # [ Http to Https ]
    Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

2 - Using rewrite cond (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com 
    # [ Http to Https ]
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

3 - using rewrite outside virtual host

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !manage.example.com
    RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

or

```
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !manage.example.com
    RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Bonus - More infos :

if you want to use your regexp var

```
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1
```

(.*) = catch all in regexp

$1 = result var, and it will start with / (so no need an extra / before)

R = redirect status code, here you have the list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

L = flag which mean Last, here you have the flag list codes:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

once configuration has been changed, apache need to be restarted

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `RewriteRule` is incorrect, so try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For more information, head over to the [Apache Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS).

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule is incorrect.
You forgot the rewriteCond to check if you're in HTTP or HTTPS.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```